# Creating Group Page Programmatically Sitefinity Backend

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitefinity

I've searched and I can't find any documentation on how to create a Group Page in the sitefinity API. I know how to create a page programmatically.

```
    var pageDataId = Guid.NewGuid();

    PageManager manager = PageManager.GetManager();
    PageData pageData = null;
    PageNode pageNode = null;

    // Get the parent node Id
    if (parentPageNodeId == Guid.Empty)
    {
        parentPageNodeId = SiteInitializer.CurrentFrontendRootNodeId;
    }

    PageNode parent = manager.GetPageNode(parentPageNodeId);

    // Check whether exists
    var initialPageNode = manager.GetPageNodes().Where(n => n.Id == pageId).SingleOrDefault();

    if (initialPageNode != null)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Create the page
    pageData = manager.CreatePageData(pageDataId);
    pageData.HtmlTitle = pageName;
    pageData.Title = pageName;
    pageData.Description = pageName;
    pageData.Culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString();
    pageData.UiCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString();

    pageNode = manager.CreatePage(parent, pageId, NodeType.Standard);
    pageNode.Page = pageData;
    pageNode.Name = pageName;
    pageNode.Description = pageName;
    pageNode.Title = pageName;
    pageNode.UrlName = Regex.Replace(pageName.ToLower(), @"[^\w\-\!\$\'\(\)\=\@\d_]+", "-");
    pageNode.ShowInNavigation = true;
    pageNode.DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
    pageNode.LastModified = DateTime.UtcNow;

    // Check whether home page
    if (isHomePage)
    {
        SystemManager.CurrentContext.CurrentSite.SetHomePage(pageId);
    }

    manager.SaveChanges();

    // Publish
    var bag = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    bag.Add("ContentType", typeof(PageNode).FullName);
    WorkflowManager.MessageWorkflow(pageId, typeof(PageNode), null, "Publish", false, bag);
}
```

This creates a regular page. I've tried changing the NodeType from standard to NodeType.Group and leaving the rest of the code as is. However this throws an exception "The current page is not standard page." I've looked for pageNode properties to make the page a group page rather than a regular page but I can't find any. If anyone knows how to do this I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

the exception is probably being thrown because you are attempting to create PageData for the created Group node. I believe that Group nodes do not have page data, but rather serve only to group other page nodes.

try removing the creation and assignment of the pageData to the PageGroup.Page property, and that should allow you to save the created page node.

Also if you install the [sitefinity SDK](http://www.sitefinity.com/resources/tools/software-development-kit) there's a SampleUtilities class in the resources folder that has a lot of helper methods for creating pages, templates, etc that serves as a great reference point for working with the API.

I hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This is some code that might help you:

```
// Define our new view
        var templateIconView = new TemplateIconView { ID = TemplateIconViewControlId };

        var pageManager = PageManager.GetManager();
        pageManager.Provider.SuppressSecurityChecks = true;

        // Get the root
        var parentNode = pageManager.GetPageNode(SiteInitializer.SitefinityNodeId);

        // Check whether exists
        var initialPageNode = pageManager.GetPageNodes().SingleOrDefault(n => n.Id == AdditionalToolsPageId);
        if (initialPageNode != null) {

            pageManager.Delete(initialPageNode);
            pageManager.SaveChanges();

        }

        var homePageNode = pageManager.GetPageNodes().SingleOrDefault(n => n.Id == HomePageId);
        if (homePageNode != null) {

            pageManager.Delete(homePageNode);
            pageManager.SaveChanges();
        }

        // Create the Group Page Node
        var groupPageNode = pageManager.CreatePage(parentNode, AdditionalToolsPageId, NodeType.Group);
        groupPageNode.Name = "KonstruiTools";
        groupPageNode.Description.SetString("Konstrui Tools", true);
        groupPageNode.Title.SetString("Konstrui Tools", true);
        groupPageNode.UrlName = Regex.Replace("Konstrui Tools", @"[^\w\-\!\$\'\(\)\=\@\d_]+", "-").ToLower();
        groupPageNode.ShowInNavigation = true;
        groupPageNode.DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
        groupPageNode.LastModified = DateTime.UtcNow;

        pageManager.SaveChanges();

        // Create the actual page PageData
        var pageData = pageManager.CreatePageData(HomePageId);
        pageData.HtmlTitle = "Configure Template Icons";
        pageData.Title = "Configure Template Icons";
        pageData.Description = "Configure Template Icons";
        pageData.Culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString();
        pageData.UiCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString();
        pageData.EnableViewState = true;
        pageData.EnableViewStateMac = true;

        // Add our control to the page with default permissions
        var control = pageManager.CreateControl<PageControl>(templateIconView, Constants.VALUE_DEFAULT_BACKEND_PLACEHOLDER);
        pageManager.SetControlDefaultPermissions(control);
        pageData.Controls.Add(control);

        // Assign the Default Backend Template
        pageData.Template = pageManager.GetTemplate(SiteInitializer.DefaultBackendTemplateId);

        // Create the actual page PageNode
        var pageNode = pageManager.CreatePage(groupPageNode, HomePageId, NodeType.Standard);
        pageNode.Page = pageData;
        pageNode.Name = "ConfigureTemplateIcons";
        pageNode.Description = "Configure Template Icons";
        pageNode.Title = "Configure Template Icons";
        pageNode.UrlName = Regex.Replace("Configure Template Icons", @"[^\w\-\!\$\'\(\)\=\@\d_]+", "-").ToLower();
        pageNode.ShowInNavigation = true;
        pageNode.DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
        pageNode.LastModified = DateTime.UtcNow;
        pageNode.RenderAsLink = true;

        pageManager.SaveChanges();

        // Publish
        var bag = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        bag.Add("ContentType", typeof(PageNode).FullName);
        WorkflowManager.MessageWorkflow(HomePageId, typeof(PageNode), null, "Publish", false, bag);


        pageManager.Provider.SuppressSecurityChecks = false;
```

This creates a grouppage inside the backend on rootlevel, wich holds another page with a control.

Comment: Where is your AdditionalToolsPageId coming from? Could possibly post that?

Comment: Nevermind I was able to figure it out for what I needed. Thank you for your post, it did guide me towards the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing. It will create a group page under another group page which is exactly what I needed for my requirements.

```
                var pageId = Guid.NewGuid();

                PageManager manager = PageManager.GetManager();

                PageNode pageNode = null;

                //Find the modules section which will serve as the 
                //parent page.
                string pageTitle = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ModulesSection"].ToString();

                //Gets the actual Modules page.
                var modulesNode = SitefinityHelper.GetPageNode(pageTitle);

                if (modulesNode.Id == Guid.Empty)
                {
                    modulesNode.Id = SiteInitializer.CurrentFrontendRootNodeId;
                }

                PageNode modulesPage = manager.GetPageNode(modulesNode.Id);

                // Check whether exists
                var initialPageNode = manager.GetPageNodes().Where(n => n.Id ==     
                pageId).SingleOrDefault();

                if (initialPageNode != null)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                //Creates the page under the Modules section as a Group Page.
                pageNode = manager.CreatePage(modulesPage, pageId, NodeType.Group);

                pageNode.Name = newModule.Name;
                pageNode.Description = newModule.Description;
                pageNode.Title = newModule.Name;
                pageNode.UrlName = Regex.Replace(newModule.Name.ToLower(), @"[^\w\-\!\$\'\(\)\=\@\d_]+", "-");
                pageNode.ShowInNavigation = true;
                pageNode.DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
                pageNode.LastModified = DateTime.UtcNow;
                manager.SaveChanges();e here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create Group page using fluent API. It's easy way given in fluent API

```
App.WorkWith()
    .Page()
    .CreateNewPageGroup()
    .Do(x => x.Title = "Testpage2")
    .Do(x => x.Name = "Testpage2")
    .Do(x => x.UrlName = "testpage2")
    .SaveChanges();
```